# putting two lists in one ListLogPlot by one modified list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I imported two sets data
one:

```
data1={{0., 5.02512*10^-10}, {0.06668, 2.99284*10^-8}, {0.13336,
3.22116*10^-8}, {0.20004, 2.58191*10^-8}, {0.26672,
  1.99125*10^-7}, {0.3334, 1.21646*10^-8}, {0.40008,
3.35916*10^-7}, {0.46676, 3.79768*10^-7}, {0.53344,
1.02102*10^-7}, {0.60012, 1.17535*10^-6}, {0.6668,
 1.72507*10^-7}, {0.73348, 1.23789*10^-6}, {0.80016,
 1.9808*10^-6}, {0.86684, 1.39616*10^-7}, {0.93352,
 4.60649*10^-6}, {1.0002, 1.39262*10^-6}, {1.06688,
3.83127*10^-6}, {1.13356, 0.0000101002}, {1.20024,
 3.26005*10^-8}, {1.26692, 0.0000229263}, {1.3336,
0.0000144712}, {1.40028, 0.000020778}, {1.46696,
 0.000134013}, {1.53364, 4.94753*10^-6}, {1.60032,
 0.00250851}, {1.667, 0.00326501}, {1.73368, 0.0000968109}, {1.80036,
 0.000207831}, {1.86704, 7.79724*10^-6}, {1.93372,
 0.0000459028}, {2.0004, 0.0000321442}, {2.06708,
 2.43685*10^-6}, {2.13376, 0.0000276559}, {2.20044,
 3.87948*10^-6}, {2.26712, 9.62673*10^-6}, {2.3338,
 0.0000130072}, {2.40048, 1.53889*10^-7}, {2.46716,
 0.0000116171}, {2.53384, 3.36691*10^-6}, {2.60052,
 3.53838*10^-6}, {2.6672, 8.3132*10^-6}, {2.73388,
 2.36251*10^-8}, {2.80056, 6.58432*10^-6}, {2.86724,
 3.33096*10^-6}, {2.93392, 1.45936*10^-6}, {3.0006,
 6.35157*10^-6}, {3.06728, 2.69642*10^-7}, {3.13396,
 4.25243*10^-6}, {3.20064, 3.49319*10^-6}, {3.26732,
 5.50908*10^-7}, {3.334, 5.33684*10^-6}, {3.40068,
 6.86369*10^-7}, {3.46736, 2.92315*10^-6}, {3.53404,
  3.88476*10^-6}, {3.60072, 1.32685*10^-7}, {3.6674,
  4.88858*10^-6}, {3.73408, 1.2985*10^-6}, {3.80076,
  2.10915*10^-6}, {3.86744, 4.63201*10^-6}, {3.93412,
  9.45702*10^-10}, {4.0008, 4.94888*10^-6}, {4.06748,
  2.37468*10^-6}, {4.13416, 1.60386*10^-6}, {4.20084,
  6.40728*10^-6}, {4.26752, 1.82055*10^-7}, {4.3342,
  6.14228*10^-6}, {4.40088, 5.175*10^-6}, {4.46756,
   1.4092*10^-6}, {4.53424, 0.000013092}};
```

second:

```
{{0., 5.02512*10^-10}, {0.06668, 6.99284*10^-8}, {0.13336,
9.22116*10^-8}, {0.20004, 9.58191*10^-8}, {0.26672,
  6.99125*10^-7}, {0.3334, 7.21646*10^-8}, {0.40008,
1.35916*10^-7}, {0.46676, 8.79768*10^-7}, {0.53344,
9.02102*10^-7}, {0.60012, 5.17535*10^-6}, {0.6668,
 9.72507*10^-7}, {0.73348, 0.23789*10^-6}, {0.80016,
 5.9808*10^-6}, {0.86684, 9.39616*10^-7}, {0.93352,
 1.60649*10^-6}, {1.0002, 5.39262*10^-6}, {1.06688,
7.83127*10^-6}, {1.13356, 0.0000101002}, {1.20024,
 5.26005*10^-8}, {1.26692, 0.0000229263}, {1.3336,
0.0000144712}, {1.40028, 0.000020778}, {1.46696,
 0.000134013}, {1.53364, 4.94753*10^-6}, {1.60032,
 0.00250851}, {1.667, 0.00326501}, {1.73368, 0.0000968109}, {1.80036,
 0.000207831}, {1.86704, 7.79724*10^-6}, {1.93372,
 0.0000459028}, {2.0004, 0.0000321442}, {2.06708,
 7.43685*10^-6}, {2.13376, 0.0000276559}, {2.20044,
 9.87948*10^-6}, {2.26712, 9.62673*10^-6}, {2.3338,
 0.0000130072}, {2.40048, 1.53889*10^-7}, {2.46716,
 0.0000116171}, {2.53384, 3.36691*10^-6}, {2.60052,
 3.53838*10^-6}, {2.6672, 8.3132*10^-6}, {2.73388,
 2.36251*10^-8}, {2.80056, 6.58432*10^-6}, {2.86724,
 3.33096*10^-6}, {2.93392, 1.45936*10^-6}, {3.0006,
 6.35157*10^-6}, {3.06728, 2.69642*10^-7}, {3.13396,
 4.25243*10^-6}, {3.20064, 3.49319*10^-6}, {3.26732,
 5.50908*10^-7}, {3.334, 5.33684*10^-6}, {3.40068,
 6.86369*10^-7}, {3.46736, 2.92315*10^-6}, {3.53404,
  3.88476*10^-6}, {3.60072, 1.32685*10^-7}, {3.6674,
  4.88858*10^-6}, {3.73408, 1.2985*10^-6}, {3.80076,
  2.10915*10^-6}, {3.86744, 4.63201*10^-6}, {3.93412,
  9.45702*10^-10}, {4.0008, 4.94888*10^-6}, {4.06748,
  2.37468*10^-6}, {4.13416, 1.60386*10^-6}, {4.20084,
  6.40728*10^-6}, {4.26752, 1.82055*10^-7}, {4.3342,
  6.14228*10^-6}, {4.40088, 5.175*10^-6}, {4.46756,
   1.4092*10^-6}, {4.53424, 0.000013092}};
```

The desired case is: plotting by `ListLogPlot` of two sets in one plot. But, before plotting, the second one must be multiplied by `100` for preventing of overlapping plots on each other. `100` must be multiplied to the second column of second data. I mean:

```
 `{0., 100*5.02512*10^-10}, {0.06668,100*6.99284*10^-8}, {0.13336,
  100*9.22116*10^-8}, {0.20004, 100*9.58191*10^-8}, {0.26672,
  100*6.99125*10^-7}, {0.3334, 10*7.21646*10^-8}.......`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A clue might be: Use `Part` or `Transpose` to multiply only the second column of your data by 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data:

```
data3 = Thread@{data2[[All, 1]], data2[[All, 2]]*100}
ListLogPlot[{data1, data3}]
```

@eldo encourages further solutions

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, {#1, 100 #2} & @@@ data2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, # {1, 100} & /@ data2}]
```

[image]